# Node, Express, MongoDB: Creating a schema with an array of objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, schema, mongoose-schema

Here's my desired schema:

```
{
    username: "taimoor",
    pairs: [
        {
            code: "CA",
            site: "google.ca"
        },
        {
            code: "US",
            site: "google.com"
        },
        {
            code: "GB",
            site: "google.co.uk"
        }
    ]
    date: 1574880349,
}
```

Here's my current schema:

```
const redirectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    pairs: [
        // What do I place here?
    ],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
```

I don't know how to proceed and implement this using `mongoose`. Should I create another schema called `Pair`? And if so:

- How do I ensure the pairs will be valid?
- How do I add a `Pair` to "pairs" programmatically?

Thanks for your time, this is my first time using NoSQL.

Comment: Hi, did you check my answer? If so, please give some feedback whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an inner schema for pairs. This way you can apply required or other validations to the pairs.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const redirectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  pairs: [
    new mongoose.Schema({
      code: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      site: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    })
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Redirect", redirectionSchema);
```

And you can use the following App.js to create a document with username and pairs, or add another pair to an existing document.

App.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Redirect = require("./models/redirect");
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/redirectDB";

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());

mongoose
  .connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));

app.post("/redirect", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await Redirect.create(req.body);
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});

app.post("/redirect/:id/pair", async (req, res) => {
  const { code, site } = req.body;

  try {
    const result = await Redirect.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {
        $push: {
          pairs: { code, site }
        }
      },
      { new: true }
    );

    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

To create username and pairs send a post requrest to the url `http://localhost:3000/redirect` like this:

```
{
    "username": "taimoor",
    "pairs": [
        {
            "code": "CA",
            "site": "google.ca"
        },
        {
            "code": "US",
            "site": "google.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

The response will be like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5ddecfcb3cd5c035b4c31d95",
    "username": "taimoor",
    "pairs": [
        {
            "_id": "5ddecfcb3cd5c035b4c31d97",
            "code": "CA",
            "site": "google.ca"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ddecfcb3cd5c035b4c31d96",
            "code": "US",
            "site": "google.com"
        }
    ],
    "date": "2019-11-27T19:34:35.781Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

And later we can add a new pair to this document using a post request to this url `http://localhost:3000/redirect/5ddecfcb3cd5c035b4c31d95/pair`. The id in the url is the id we previosuly created, and got in the response.

Request:

```
{
    "code": "GB",
    "site": "google.co.uk"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "_id": "5ddecfcb3cd5c035b4c31d95",
    "username": "taimoor",
    "pairs": [
        {
            "_id": "5ddecfcb3cd5c035b4c31d97",
            "code": "CA",
            "site": "google.ca"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ddecfcb3cd5c035b4c31d96",
            "code": "US",
            "site": "google.com"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5dded01693be502168a0f794",
            "code": "GB",
            "site": "google.co.uk"
        }
    ],
    "date": "2019-11-27T19:34:35.781Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. $push works for me. Any idea how I can make the `code` value of every pair unique? I'm trying to fix that problem now and it's surprisingly difficult

Comment: @TaimoorAhmad I will look at tomorrow, but maybe you can ask another new question so that others also can reply.

Comment: Good idea, I will do that. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Model**

```
const redirectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    pairs: [
        {
            _id: false,
            code: { type: String },
            site: { type: String }
        }
    ],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

const Redirection = mongoose.model('Redirection', redirectionSchema);
```

**Use**

```
const redirection = new Redirection({
    username: "taimoor",
    pairs: [
        {
            code: "CA",
            site: "google.ca"
        },
        {
            code: "US",
            site: "google.com"
        },
        {
            code: "GB",
            site: "google.co.uk"
        }
    ],
    date: new Date(1574880349),
})

redirection.save();
```

**Example database output**

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ddecc4c6dd3760c40ff354b"
  },
  "username": "taimoor",
  "pairs": [
    {
      "code": "CA",
      "site": "google.ca"
    },
    {
      "code": "US",
      "site": "google.com"
    },
    {
      "code": "GB",
      "site": "google.co.uk"
    }
  ],
  "date": {
    "$date": "1970-01-19T05:28:00.349Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: remember to add a question ;)

Comment: Thank you. Why is the _id of the pair set to false? Since it's not a schema wouldn't that have no effect?

Comment: Setting _id to false is optional, I do it when an element is added to the array does not generate a new _id, it depends on the scenario, general does not have much use.